# How to detect or run a function only when user clicks browser's back button in / from a specific component in angular 4?

Tags: angular

i have 3 components in which when navigating/routing from component 1 to component 2 i use "skipLocationChange" which doesn't store component 2's path in history like wise the same from component's 2 to component's 3, now the idea that i was using "skipLocationChange" is to make disable the angular 4's app's routing path storing in history, but the problem is if i press the back button from component 3 it navigates to component 1... here i used component 3 in a modal hence while navigating back the component 1 appears in the same modal which is an issue...

how can i solve this? by disabling browser back function? or by running a function that closes the modal on pressing browser's back button?

Comment: or is the any way to restric navigation to particular component from a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this by restrictng the navigation to particular url by using **canActiveGuard** <3!